# Accessing the content of a javascripted table by program

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website ‘A’ which for many years has scraped information from a constantly-changing table on another website ‘B’ (with their permission) for use on my site.  I used PHP/curl_exec to capture the table and search its content for the rows that I needed.

The source website ‘B’ has now recoded the table, and only the column headings are visible in the source code.  All the variable content is added by javascript, and I haven’t found a way of accessing it by a PHP search after downloading the page.  The table appears as normal on the screen, and can be searched manually using Ctrl-F.  But my existing PHP code fails to find content which is visible on screen.

My question is:  Is there a way of accessing the table content on website ‘B’ by program, preferably PHP, in order to select some of it for use on my website ‘A’?

Website ‘B’ is http://www.pla.co.uk  and the table is at
http://www.pla.co.uk/hydrographics/ltoverview.cfm

Comment: Presumably it is the tide data you want - which can be [found here](http://www.pla.co.uk/hydrographics/ajax/ltoverview.php) - if you have permission create a proxy script ( there is no `access-control-allow-origin` header so CORS is out) to fetch the data

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, it's the up-to-date tide data that I want, and the file you identified is exactly what I need.  I've altered my PHP code to access that file and fetch the data.  All now working again.  Many thanks.